# MongoDB ttl index behave unexpected

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

We currently have a ttl index on a timestamp in MongoDB.

Before we had an ttl `expireAfterSeconds` : 604800 seconds -> 1 week of documents.

A few weeks ago we change this to a TTL index of `31536000` seconds -> 365 days.

But MongoDB still removes documents after 7 days instead of 365.

- MongoDB version: 4.2.18
- MongoDB running hosted Atlas / AWS

Indexes in database:

```
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { _id: 1 },
    name: '_id_',
    ns: '<DB>.<COLLECTION>'
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { id: 1, ts: 1 },
    name: 'id_1_ts_1',
    ns: '<DB>.<COLLECTION>
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { ts: 1 },
    name: 'ts_1',
    ns: '<DB>.<COLLECTION>',
    expireAfterSeconds: 31536000
  }
]
```

We have an environmental variable to set the TTL index on each start of the application,
the code to set the ttl index looks like this:

```
      await collection.createIndex(
        { ts: 1 },
        {
          expireAfterSeconds: ENV.<Number>
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      if ((e as any).codeName == "IndexOptionsConflict") {
        await collection.dropIndex("ts_1");
        await collection.createIndex(
          { ts: 1 },
          {
            expireAfterSeconds: ENV.<Number>
          }
        );
      }
    }
```

as seen from the indexes, the TTL index should remove documents after one year?
Why does it behave like this? Any insights?

Comment: How did you change the `expireAfterSeconds` value for the index?

Comment: Ive updated the description above with how we do it.

Comment: I think, you need to specify the _index name_ in the `await collection.dropIndex("ts");`.

Comment: We actually do it, I accidentally removed it while removing the real key names. Edited abobe.

Comment: Maybe you should drop the index first, and then create the new index.

Answer (score -1):

I would look into the [collMod](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/command/collMod/#dbcmd.collMod) command

Comment: Please add some code to address the issue or link to a similar question with an answer. More description needed